# Refactoring / layout of functional Scala

Tags: scala, refactoring, functional-programming, coding-style

This one liner...

```
 Console.println(io.Source.fromFile("names.txt").getLines.mkString.split(",").map{x:String => x.slice(1, x.length -1)}.sortBy { x => x}.zipWithIndex.map{t =>{ (t._2 +1)*(t._1.map{_.toChar - "A"(0).toChar + 1}.sum)}}.sum);
```

... is my solution to [Project Euler problem 22](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=22). It seems to work, and it's written in (my attempt at) functional style.

This example is a bit extreme, but my question is a bit more general - how do you prefer to write/format/comment functional style code? The functional approach seems to encourage a sequence of method calls, which I find can get unreadable, and also leaves nowhere obvious to put comments.

Also, when I write procedural code, I find I write small methods each with one purpose and with meaningful names. When I write functional code, I seem to be developing a habit that produces lines a little like the one above, where (to me) the meaning is difficult to decipher - and also the individual computations are difficult to re-use elsewhere. Quite a lot of the functional code examples I see on the web are similarly terse (to me) obscure.

What should I be doing? Writing little functions for each part of the computatation with names meaningful in the current context? (even if they're little more than a wrapper for map, say?)

For the example I've given, what are better ways of writing it, and presenting it?

(Like all style questions, this one is subjective. There's no reason it should get argumentative, though!)

Comment: I don't have enough experience with Scala to give you good advice, but it might be helpful if you were to break each `map` onto a different line? I'm interested to find out what real Scala-ites have to say about this.

Comment: A very important and language-/paradigma-agnostic rule is not to make lines longer than 80 (or another sensible value) characters. 190 chars is just insane (and if you're code golfing, at least get it down to 130 or you'll never beat perl! ;) ).

Comment: Agreed, it's that long for pedagogical reasons. But my question is partly about how best to split it into smaller chunks, other than choosing breaks just to make the lines < 80 characters. I'm not code golfing, but I am trying to improve my functional programming...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A trivial first-attempt at tidying it up is to just remove the leading `Console.` the trailing `;` and the explicit `:String` type - all of which are unnecessary - add some indentation and import io.Source:

```
import io.Source
println(
  Source.fromFile("names.txt").getLines.mkString.split(",").map{
    x => x.slice(1, x.length -1)
  }.sortBy {x => x}.zipWithIndex.map{
    t =>{ (t._2 +1)*(t._1.map{_.toChar - "A"(0).toChar + 1}.sum)}
  }.sum
)
```

The next step is to clean it up a little, use pattern matching when mapping over list of tuples and `identity` instead of `x=>x`. `toChar` is also unnecessary for characters, and single quotes can be used to represent character literals.

```
import io.Source
println(
  Source.fromFile("names.txt").getLines.mkString.split(",").map {
    x => x.slice(1, x.length -1)
  }.sortBy(identity).zipWithIndex.map {
    case (v, idx) =>{ (idx+1)*(v.map{_ - 'A' + 1}.sum)}
  }.sum
)
```

A few more changes also help make the intent of the code far clearer:

```
import io.Source
println(
  Source.fromFile("names.txt").getLines.mkString.split(",")
  .map { _.stripPrefix("\"").stripSuffix("\"") }
  .sortBy(identity)
  .map { _.map{_ - 'A' + 1}.sum }
  .zipWithIndex
  .map { case (v, idx) => (idx+1) * v }
  .sum
)
```

The next step, to make it more "functional", is to break it into "functions" (*sneaky, huh?*).  Ideally each function will have a name clearly expressing its purpose, and it will be short (aim for it to be a single expression, so braces aren't required):

```
import io.Source

def unquote(s:String) = s.stripPrefix("\"").stripSuffix("\"")

def wordsFrom(fname:String) =
  Source.fromFile(fname).getLines.mkString.split(",").map(unquote)

def letterPos(c:Char) = c - 'A' + 1

println(
  wordsFrom("names.txt")
  .sortBy(identity)
  .map { _.map(letterPos).sum }
  .zipWithIndex
  .map { case (v, idx) => (idx+1) * v }
  .sum
)
```

`wordsFrom` is an obvious 1-liner, but I split it for easier formatting on stackOverflow

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a neophyte at Scala so this is really useful stuff. The refactoring is pretty much what I would have done. I've somehow gained the (probably erroneous) view that this small, single-expression function approach wasn't the way to do things, though.

Comment: I had to roll it back a couple of notches after seeing the code full-screen, it didn't look much better than the original after I broke down *everything* into functions :)

Comment: +1 This is pretty close to what I'd consider a perfect answer to this question.  Minor nitpick: wouldn't `sorted` be preferable to `sortBy(identity)`?

Comment: @Aaron Novstrup, yeah sorted seens better.

Comment: Minor nitpick: I don't like `fname`. Remember, as of Scala 2.8, parameter names are part of the public contract of a method, because of named arguments. What about `path`?

Comment: sorted vs. sortBy. I couldn't get sorted to work (got some compiler error). Now, it was probably another error nothing to do with sorted (it wasn't compiling at all at that point), but I do find it difficult sometimes to work out what the Scala compiler errors really mean.

Comment: @Kevin Interesting that I picked some of the same refactorings you did. For example, splitting the last `map` into two computations.

Comment: @Daniel My thinking was to separate the letterPos operation from the indexing, rather than from the multiplication - the approach *should* be more efficient.  I actually went all the way to refactoring into individual functions, just changed my mind afterwards, it looked *less* readable to my eyes.  In real life I'd do that on demand if the code had to be reused.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I think might be a better way to lay it out:

```
Console.println(
    io.Source.fromFile("names.txt")
    .getLines.mkString.split(",")
    .map{x:String => x.slice(1, x.length -1)}
    .sortBy { x => x}
    .zipWithIndex
    .map{t =>{ (t._2 +1)*(t._1.map{_.toChar - "A"(0).toChar + 1}.sum)}}
    .sum);
```

I feel like deep in the recesses of my brain there's some algorithm that makes decisions about code-layout trade-offs between horizontal and vertical space, but I don't seem to have direct access to enable me to articulate it.  :)

Regarding introducing names rather than using lambdas, I think what I typically do is, if I am tempted to put a short comment describing the intent of the code, but a good identifier name may do the same, then I may factor a one-time lambda into a named function in order to get the readability benefit of the identifier name.  The line with the `toChar` calls is the only one above that looks like a candidate to me.  (To be clear, I'd factor (part of) the lambda inside the `map`, but the `map` call itself.)  Alternatively, the introduction of vertical whitespace gives you a place to hang a `//comment` which is an alternative to introducing an identifier name.

(Disclaimer: I don't write Scala, so if anything I say conflicts with style conventions, then ignore me :), but I imagine a lot of this advice is mostly-language-agnostic.)

Answer (score 4):

Speaking strictly to how to *format* that code, without making any structural changes, I'd do it like this:

```
Console println (
  (
    io.Source
    fromFile "names.txt"
    getLines ()
    mkString ""
    split ","
    map (x => x.slice(1, x.length - 1))
    sortBy (x => x)
    zipWithIndex
  )
  map (t => (t._2 + 1) * (t._1 map (_.toChar - "A"(0).toChar + 1) sum) )
  sum
)
```

Or, perhaps, to get around the parameterless methods, I'd do this:

```
Console println (
  io.Source
  .fromFile("names.txt")
  .getLines
  .mkString
  .split(",")
  .map(x => x.slice(1, x.length - 1))
  .sortBy(x => x)
  .zipWithIndex
  .map(t => (t._2 + 1) * (t._1 map (_.toChar - "A"(0).toChar + 1) sum) )
  .sum
)
```

Note that there is plenty of space for comments, but, generally speaking, what
is being done is usually clear. People not used to it might sometimes get lost
halfway through, without variables to keep track of the meaning/type of the
transformed value.

Now, some things I'd do differently are:

```
println ( // instead of Console println
  Source // put import elsewhere
  .fromFile("names.txt")
  .mkString // Unless you want to get rid of /n, which is unnecessary here
  .split(",")
  .map(x => x.slice(1, x.length - 1))
  .sorted // instead of sortBy
  .zipWithIndex
  .map { // use { only for multiple statements and, as in this case, pattern matching
    case (c, index) => (index + 1) * (c map (_ - 'A' + 1) sum) // chars are chars
  }
  .sum
)
```

I'd also not do sum and multiplying in the same step, so:

```
  .sorted
  .map(_ map (_ - 'A' + 1) sum)
  .zipWithIndex
  .map { case (av, index) => av * (index + 1) }
  .sum
```

Finally, I don't much like that string resizing, so I might resort to regex instead. Add a little refactoring, and this is something I'd probably write:

```
  import scala.io.Source
  def names = Source fromFile "names.txt" mkString

  def wordExtractor = """"(.*?)"""".r
  def words = for {
    m <- wordExtractor findAllIn names matchData
  } yield m group 1

  def alphabeticValue(s: String) = s map (_ - 'A' + 1) sum
  def wordsAV = words.toList.sorted map alphabeticValue

  def multByIndex(t: (Int, Int)) = t match {
    case (av, index) => av * (index + 1)
  }
  def wordsAVByIndex = wordsAV.zipWithIndex map multByIndex

  println(wordsAVByIndex.sum)
```

**EDIT**

The next step would be a renaming refactoring -- choosing names that better convey what each part of the code is doing. Ken suggested better names in the comments, and I'd appropriate them for one more variant (it also showcases nicely how much *better* naming improves readability).

```
import scala.io.Source
def rawData = Source fromFile "names.txt" mkString

// I'd rather write "match" than "m" in the next snippet, but
// the former is a keyword in Scala, so "m" has become more
// common in my code than "i". Also, make the return type of
// getWordsOf clear, because iterators can be tricky.
// Returning a list, however, makes a much less cleaner
// definition.

def wordExtractor = """"(.*?)"""".r
def getWordsOf(input: String): Iterator[String] = for {
  m <- wordExtractor findAllIn input matchData
} yield m group 1
def wordList = getWordsOf(rawData).toList

// I stole letterPosition from Kevin's solution. There, I said it. :-)

def letterPosition(c: Char) = c.toUpper - 'A' + 1 // .toUpper isn't necessary
def alphabeticValueOfWord(word: String) = word map letterPosition sum
def alphabeticValues = wordList.sorted map alphabeticValueOfWord

// I don't like multAVByIndex, but I haven't decided on a better
// option yet. I'm not very fond of declaring methods that return
// functions either, but I find that better than explicitly handling
// tuples (oh, for the day tuples/arguments are unified!).

def multAVByIndex = (alphabeticValue: Int, index: Int) => 
  alphabeticValue * (index + 1)
def scores = alphabeticValues.zipWithIndex map multAVByIndex.tupled

println(scores sum)
```

Comment: I like this the best. I'd rename some variables to make things a little clearer: `names -> rawData` (reflect that it's one big string), `wordsAV -> alphabeticalValues` (avoid the acronym), `wordsAVByIndex -> scores` (avoid the acronym, call them scores because that's what Project Euler calls them)

Comment: @Ken I didn' get to rename refactoring. :-) Indeed, I like all of your suggestions better than what the variables are presently named. Maybe I should even change the code, to make it more readable?

Comment: yes, please change it (by adding another variant to your answer) so that future readers of the page can benefit from your views on this.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kevin's solution,

the key is to split the functionality clearly and neatly, taking in consideration of reusability and readability.

To make the code even shorter and cleaner, it seems that the for expression can be used.

```
def inputString(inputFile: String) = io.Source.fromFile(inputFile).getLines.mkString

def inputWords(input: String) = input.split("[,\"]").filter("" != )

Console.println {
    (for { (s, idx) <- inputWords(inputString("names.txt")).sorted.zipWithIndex }
        yield s.map(_ - 'A' + 1).sum * (idx + 1)).sum
}
```

The s.map(_-'A'+1) part can be further put into a function, say wordSum, if you want it to be more distinct.

Comment: Thanks. It's all about personal preference, of course, but I find Kevin's reworking clearer.