# What is the accepted/recommended syntax for Scala code with lots of method-chaining?

Tags: scala, syntax, coding-style, method-chaining

In Scala I tend to favour writing large chained expressions over many smaller expressions with `val` assignments.  At my company we've sort of evolved a style for this type of code.  Here's a totally contrived example (idea is to show an expression with lots of chained calls):

```
import scala.util.Random
val table = (1 to 10) map { (Random.nextInt(100), _) } toMap

def foo: List[Int] =
  (1 to 100)
    .view
    .map { _ + 3 }
    .filter { _ > 10 }
    .flatMap { table.get }
    .take(3)
    .toList
```

Daniel Spiewak's [Scala Style Guide](http://www.codecommit.com/scala-style-guide.pdf) (pdf), which I generally like, suggests the leading dot notation in the chained method calls may be bad (see doc: Method Invocation / Higher-Order Functions), though it doesn't cover multi-line expressions like this directly.

Is there another, more accepted/idiomatic way to write the function `foo` above?

**UPDATE: 28-Jun-2011**

Lots of great answers and discussion below.  There doesn't appear to be a 100% "you must do it this way" answer, so I'm going to accept the most popular answer by votes, which is currently the for comprehension approach.  Personally, I think I'm going to stick with the leading-dot notation for now and accept the risks that come with it.

Comment: I'm going to dare to disagree with the Scala experts below and say I prefer your leading . to all the alternatives in the answers below. The for comprehension requires the invention of names that I don't think are necessary in many cases, the .-free bracketed one isn't as clear at the first glance that it's a set of operations on one list, rather than some side-effecting (I, know, spit) operations.

Comment: @Paul - The leading `.` notation *is* nice, and certainly feels right.  But so does performing in a orchestra without a conductor, or having gratuitous sex without a condom - there are very definite reasons why we don't do these things though.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy into those analogies - theu seem overstretched to me, and the downsides of the . notation manageable. You might also like to look at one Kevin Wright's answer to my similar question here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238902 /refactoring-layout-of-functional-scala where the leading . is in evidence :)

Comment: @Paul - You'll note in the quoted answer that I was using leading `.`s within an argument to a function call.  The use of `sortBy` and `zipWithIndex` also made a comprehension less suitable for that particular scenario.  As I stated above, the leading dots feel nice, they just need to be constrained to the prophylactic safety of surrounding braces or parentheses if you'll be using them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The example is slightly unrealistic, but for complex expressions, it's often far cleaner to use a comprehension:

```
def foo = {
  val results = for {
    x <- (1 to 100).view
    y = x + 3 if y > 10
    z <- table get y
  } yield z
  (results take 3).toList
}
```

The other advantage here is that you can name intermediate stages of the computation, and make it more self-documenting.

If brevity is your goal though, this can easily be made into a one-liner (the point-free style helps here):

```
def foo = (1 to 100).view.map{3+}.filter{10<}.flatMap{table.get}.take(3).toList
//or
def foo = ((1 to 100).view map {3+} filter {10<} flatMap {table.get} take 3).toList
```

and, as always, optimise your algorithm where possible:

```
def foo = ((1 to 100).view map {3+} filter {10<} flatMap {table.get} take 3).toList
def foo = ((4 to 103).view filter {10<} flatMap {table.get} take 3).toList
def foo = ((11 to 103).view flatMap {table.get} take 3).toList
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could throw `=` into a for comprehension.  Suddenly they're even more useful.  Good info.  I like this as an alternate syntax.  Re: optimizations -- I just threw in stupid extra operations to make the example artificially longer.

Comment: @overthink - I know you did :)  Though the principle still stands!

Answer (score 11):

I wrap the entire expression into a set of parenthesis to group things and avoid dots if possible,

```
def foo: List[Int] =
  ( (1 to 100).view
    map { _ + 3 }
    filter { _ > 10 }
    flatMap { table.get }
    take(3)
    toList )
```

Comment: I hadn't considered using parens. I think I prefer this style to the leading dot notation, and it should deal neatly with any semicolon inference issues.

Comment: Interesting, but seems like a bit of a hack. I prefer the dots, so it's clearer what each line does, without having to look around for parentheses several lines away.

Comment: @luigi - obviously, you'd also combine indentation with the  parentheses, so that it's clear exactly what's going on from "big picture" visual clues

Comment: @Aaron It's my own prefered style, but parameter-less methods throw a wrench into the engine. In those cases, the best way is to put the expression to which the parameter-less method applies inside parenthesis, with the postfix method in dot notation -- like it's done with `(1 to 100).view`, in fact. If not for `view`, you could write `1<new line>to 100<new line>map {...} etc`. An alternative is put the postfix as the last method inside a parenthesis -- like it's done with `toList` here.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how extempore does it.  You can't go wrong.

```
(specMember
  setInfo   subst(env, specMember.info.asSeenFrom(owner.thisType, sym.owner))
  setFlag   (SPECIALIZED)
  resetFlag (DEFERRED | CASEACCESSOR | ACCESSOR | LAZY)
)
```

Authentic compiler source!

Answer (score 5):

I prefer lots of `val`s:

```
def foo = {
  val range = (1 to 100).view
  val mappedRange = range map { _+3 }
  val importantValues = mappedRange filter { _ > 10 } flatMap { table.get }
  (importantValues take 3).toList
}
```

Because I don't know what you want to purpose with your code, I chose random names for the `val`s.
There is a big advantage to choose `val`s instead of the other mentioned solutions:

It is obvious what your code does. In your example and in the solutions mentioned in most other answers anyone does **not** know at first sight what it does. There is too much information in one expression. Only in a for-expression, mentioned by @Kevin, it is possible to choose telling names but I don't like them because:

1. They need more lines of code
2. They are slower due to pattern match the declared values (I mentioned this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447631/value-assignment-inside-for-loop-in-scala/6448044#6448044)).
3. Just my opinion, but I think they look ugly

Comment: Isn't it cheating to non-idiomatically combine the `filter` and `flatMap` on the same line and then claim that this approach requires fewer lines?  Which doesn't mean to say that I dislike the approach in general, I'd be especially keen to see some profile results following your comparative analysis of the generated bytecode.

Comment: I executed both, your and my code, several millions times (with warm-up) and I came to the result, that my code is a bit faster. But the difference is negligible. And I don't think that my code is non-idiomatic because it filters the important values in both, the `filter` and `flatMap` method.

Comment: fair point, now let me just go and rewrite the comprehension in a single line with semicolons, on the basis that every operation is related because it's a transform of some description :)

Comment: Then the code will be unreadable. Ok, I see my argumentation with the lines of code is not the best.

Answer (score 2):

My rule: if the expression fits on a single (80-120 character) line, keep it on one line and omit the dots wherever possible:

```
def foo: List[Int] = 
   (1 to 100).view map { _ + 3 } filter { _ > 10 } flatMap table.get take 3 toList
```

As Kevin pointed out, the point-free style may improve brevity (but could harm readability for developers not familiar with it):

```
def foo: List[Int] = 
   (1 to 100).view map{3+} filter{10<} flatMap table.get take 3 toList
```

<strike>The leading dot notation is perfectly acceptable if you need to separate the expression over multiple lines due to length. Another reason to use this notation is when the operations need individual comments.</strike> If you need to spread an expression over multiple lines, due to its length or the need to comment individual operations, it's best to wrap the entire expression in parens (as [Alex Boisvert suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471949/what-is-the-accepted-recommended-syntax-for-scala-code-with-lots-of-method-chaini/6473134#6473134). In these situations, each (logical) operation should go on its own line (i.e. each operation goes on a single line, except where multiple consecutive operations can be described succinctly by a single comment):

```
def foo: List[Int] = 
   ( (1 to 100).view
     map { _ + 3 }
     filter { _ > 10 }
     flatMap table.get
     take 3
     toList )
```

This technique avoids potential [semicolon inference issues](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscala%5D+semicolon+inference) that can arise when using leading dot notation or calling a 0-arg method at the end of the expression.

Comment: That trailing `.toList` is a slight risk, I try to avoid them because they can mess with semicolon inference (just as the leading-dot style can)

Comment: @Kevin Can you elaborate on that point in your answer (maybe with an example)?  I know I've heard about the issue on the mailing list, but I've never had it come up personally.

Comment: Good point about commenting.  The parens-grouped, leading-dot, and for comprehension approaches all allow for per-operation comments quite nicely.

Comment: I'd still favour putting `.toList` outside the parens, which feels to me like a better representation of the code's intent.  You can then drop the explicit typing without loosing *too* much sleep...

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to avoid using dot for things like `map` and `filter`. So I would probably write it like the following:

```
def foo: List[Int] =
  (1 to 100).view map { x =>
    x + 3 } filter { x =>
    x > 10 } flatMap { table.get } take(3) toList
```

The leading dot notation is very readable. I might start using that.

Comment: I also find the leading dot notation quite readable, but I wasn't sure if that was just because I've gotten used to it :)