# Indent setting for scala new line dot notation in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have all of my tabs set correctly in Intellij for using 2 spaces however I don't know where to modify a setting to give me 2 spaces after a newline using dot notation. Whenever I drop to a new line starting with a dot it gives me 4 spaces. [image]

Also if I use Continuation Indent = 1 then I get 1 space indent when working with datasets but this behavior isn't consistent so not sure why yet it works sometimes but not other times.

[image]

Comment: Do you have "2" spaces for "Tab Size", "Indent" and "Continuation indent" in "Settings | Editor | Code Style | Scala"? Also please try to disable "Indents Detection" and "EditorConfig support" in "Settings | Editor | Code Style".

Comment: It will be somewhere in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Scala

Comment: @y.bedrov I do have 2 in my settings and tried your recommendations but same issue of 4 spaces when new line starts with a dot.

Comment: Do you use any custom plugins "Settings | Plugins - Custom"?

Comment: I use some plugin but nothing that would interfere with formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the behaviour you want by going to File -> Settings; Editor -> Code Style -> Scala; Tabs and Indents; Continuation Indent = 1.

However it is normal Scala formatting to have the dot on the previous line (in your case like this):

```
val group1: RDD[(Int, Double)] = sortedCache.
```

and that gives an indent of 2 spaces on the second line without needing to change the IDE settings.

Comment: Thank you! that does it. I've been trying to figure out the best way to chain many methods and it seems like there isn't a universally recommended approach and I have concluded that leading dots seem to be the easiest to read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471949/what-is-the-accepted-recommended-syntax-for-scala-code-with-lots-of-method-chain

Comment: weird. only thing I just noticed is that with that new setting if I use a dataset the indent becomes one space as opposed to 2. (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

After having a play around with my IntelliJ settings, I *believe* that I have found it:

`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `Scala` -> `Wrapping and Braces (tab)` -> `Align when multiline (option under "Chained method calls")`

[image: Indentation]